# Evaluation of Asterisk & pjsip for IMS support

Tags: client, asterisk, pjsip

I want to work on an open source project, that has VoIP infra already in it, to add IMS support in it. Specifically IMS client support that is compliant with 3gpp rel 9.

For that I am thinking on using asterisk or pjsip code. As I am targeting to work in C and Linux these two projects suit my prerequisites. Also they are very stable products hence I am hoping to start working on any of them without any need to fix a bug which can delay my goal.

The question is which project to choose to start working upon - asterisk or pjsip?

I am working on to make a choice so I was just hoping to get any valuable pointers from fellow programmers. Any help is really welcome. Also I will keep posting my findings and my wish list as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking compare different type of projects.

Asterisk is PBX. It is server side.

pjsip is sip stack and clients libs.

You can use both,but you can't compare pbx with clients libs.

Comment: Thanks for the response.I am aware that asterisk is a PBX and pjsip is library.Both have sip components.However asterisk can act as UA for clients registered on it. So if IMS support is added in asterisk & a decision is made when a specific extension registers on asterisk then asterisk should register on IMS server using preconfigured public/private IDs then it can extend to use IMS functionality.Moreover asterisk can support multiple client types in its local network such that PSTN devices,IMS clients,sip but non-IMS clients. Asterisk may manage if IMS registration is required for a UA or not

Comment: it is like use airplane for usual road driving. sure you can, but what sence?